# how to create CLOCKSUM column for the week?

Tags: org-mode

In column view i can use some [special columns](http://orgmode.org/manual/Special-properties.html) like CLOCKSUM (total time) and CLOCKSUM_T (time for today). How can i create column CLOCKSUM_W which would sum all the time for current week?